# SQL counting number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a way to search for a certain number of rows as a quality check. For example, we have tables that have a certain set of results that are needed.

Here is a quick table for an example:

```
ID:        Name:       Result:       Reportable:
ONE        A           10            X
TWO        B           12            X
THREE      C           1             
FOUR       D           18            X
FOUR(redo) D           11            X
```

So we are looking to double check results as there are people who accidentally report results multiple times (as in the case with ID FOUR). We have used having counts but we need the numbers to be specific and need a query to verify that number is satisfied.

In the table above we only want IDs ONE, TWO, and FOUR, however we have 4 results (one extra). Currently we have our check showing the count needed (ie 3) and the current result count (4) to show the mismatch but want a query to easily only show the result needed. We would need the redo result most of the time so we have set it so we take the latest date, but it doesn't help filter how many rows or results. I apologize if anything is confusing and I am not able to share the SQL query that we have currently. It's my first time posting so if I need to clarify anything please let me know as this seems to be very complicated. Thank you for your time.

EDIT: The details
We have one table (Table A) letting us know which results are reportable. The ones that are reportable go into another table (Table B). We have had issues in which people have made too many results reportable which overpopulates the Table B. Our old query had a count in Table B, but due to mistakes in people placing multiple reportables, samples which had many redos seem to be finished as they were all placed and met the count in Table B.

So now by using the Table A that helps tell us how many are Reportable, we want this to double check that the samples are indeed ready.

Comment: Something like this?  `select *, case when x=1 then 'Of Interest' else 'Ignore' end Action from (select ID, Name, Result, Reportable, row_number() over (partition by Name order by Id desc) x from myTable) y`

Comment: Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e387d/1

Comment: Yes JohnLBevan, that is very similar to what we have now except we have a count on the "Of Interest" (let's say 3 are needed but we have 4 instead due to the Reportable column). I'm looking to see how to obtain only the 3 results necessary. Having the 3 (or 4) results shows us that it is ready. Getting the 3 correct ones is another. I will edit and clarify hopefully.

Comment: Use me sql then filter on `reportable = ‘x’ and action = ‘Of Interest’`.

Comment: But if there is a redo on the ID, both are pushed to another table. We want to find a way to 1) check to see if the total number of IDs is correct and 2) choose the correct ID. For the example I gave let's say we need only 3 results but 4 are pushed to this other table. What if 3 re-dos were done, how would we know if the project is ready?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, you want ids that have multiple reportables.  Assuming you really mean `name`, then:

```
select name
from t
where reportable = 'X'
group by name
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: This is how we thought in the beginning. I have further clarified our instance. Thanks for the reply.